# Remove padding while scrolling horizontallly

Tags: css

There is initial space before the list. And the list is scrollable.
The space from the beginning needs to be removed while scrolling. Is it possible to do so using css?

I initially added padding before the list. But the padding is always maintaining it's space.

JSX:

```
  <div class="pt-filter-container">
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      class="item"
    >
      {{ item.label }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.filter-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 30em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  .item {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #5A6872;
    margin-right: 8px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border: 1px solid @chip-grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    position: relative;
  }
  .active {
    background-color: @red;
    color: @white;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please create an example on https://jsfiddle.net/ or share your code in your post so that we can help.

Comment: Add that space equally on the left and right of each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just i need to add margin before the 1st element instead of container that is containing it.

So the actual code will be -

```
.pt-filter-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 30em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  .pt-item {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #5A6872;
    margin-right: 8px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border: 1px solid @pt-chip-grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    position: relative;

    &:first-child {
      margin-left: 18px;
    }
  }
  .active {
    background-color: @pt-red;
    color: @pt-white;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the exact dom and css structure of your project. But can't you use something like this?

```css
overflow-x: hidden
```

or

```css
ul > li: first-child {
    padding-left: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Padding needs to be removed only while scrolling. 
I need to show the space initially. But need to remove space while user scroll horizontally.
So that user can easily cross the viewport.